Can Merrill 401k Company Legally withhold my 401k from me when it's under $5k total balance?
I've recently undergone a horrible experience with mess of a failed construction project ending in an architect suing me for a large sum of money for prints that will always be unusable to me. This is dwindling my bank accounts down to nothing and I'm attempting everything I can to sell and generate funds to get myself in a better financial state. However, Merrill, the 401k company my 401k is with, will not let me withdraw my 401k unless it's for adopting a kid or a financial hardship that's either medical or risk of foreclosure. I'm within a month or two of that becoming a reality for me. So I'm trying to get ahead of it all and do things now before it gets there. But unless I actively have legitimate medical statements 120 days or less showing every detail to why how and where and what was performed and the amount charged, then I cannot withdraw the money I have put in there. This seems like it should be illegal? Is there anything I can do about this? I probably will not use Merrill again after this ordeal. I'd much rather be in total control of my investments and savings in every aspect when I can get back to growing it again.

Not only is it legal, it's the whole point.  The government wants to encourage people to save for retirement, so they give you a tax deduction for putting money in a retirement account like a 401(k).  But if you could just take that money out whenever you want, it'd defeat the purpose.

I understand the point. And it's not like I actually want to take it out. What methods does one endeavor before reaching their end of the road and filing bankruptcy? Some people are actually good with money, and instead are simply victims of disastrous events outside of their control that lead them to no other option than to file bankruptcy.

@SirJake 401(k)s are protected in bankruptcy so they're trying to save you from yourself. You need a financial advisor ASAP.

Some 401k's allow hardship withdrawals or loans. But this is up to the plan administrator, not the broker. This information should be in the plan documents.

Merrill is your 401k administrator, but the decision of who and how can withdraw funds is up to your employer. 401k withdrawals are only allowed in limited circumstances(ref 1, ref 2), and you cannot make a non-qualified withdrawal if the plan doesn't allow that, which is what they're telling you.
A way to work around that is to roll over into an IRA and then do a non-qualified withdrawal from there (which will incur an additional 10% penalty on top of the taxes owed), or take a loan from your 401k plan. Although depending on your personal situation, neither may be actually available to you.

Loans from 401k's are not uncommon, but I don't think IRA rollovers are usually allowed, except for after-tax contributions or when you no longer work for the company.

Right, that's where personal situations become relevant. pre-tax rollovers are usually only allowed post separation, while loans are only allowed while in service, so these two are mutually exclusive. In addition, given the low balance, it could be that the plan wouldn't allow a loan at all.

I didn't even think that there might be balance-related limits.
